# Partial match case

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two columns separated by a comma below:

```
"01962424813","KSDP01"
"KSDP01","01962424813"
"8801962424813","KSDP01"
01962424813,KSDP01
1962424813,KSDP01
8801962424813,KSDP01
KSDP01,01962424813
KSDP01,1962424813
KSDP01,8801962424813
"1962424813","KSDP01"
"KSDP01","1962424813"
"KSDP01","8801962424813"
01959969994,ASDP11
"8801962424183","ASDP01"
"801962424183","KSDP11"
"01962424183","CSDP10"
"1962424183","ASDP09"
8801962424183,CSDP13
801962424183,KSDP08
01962424183,ASDP07
1962424183,CSDP05
"ASDP01","8801962424183",
"KSDP11","801962424183",
"CSDP10","01962424183"
"ASDP09","1962424183"
CSDP13,8801962424183
KSDP08,801962424183
ASDP07,01962424183
CSDP05,1962424183
01912401927,CSDP06
```

Whenever I find the substring `19` in the first column I want to swap the two values. How can I do that? Here's what I've tried:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$1=$1;if( awk '$1 ~ /19/' ){print $2,$1}else{print $1,$2}}'
```

Comment: What attempt did you make

Comment: awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$1=$1;if( awk '$1 ~ /19/' ){print $2,$1}else{print $1,$2}}'

Comment: What's the point of `$1=$1` in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," '($1 ~ /19/){temp=$1;$1=$2;$2=temp}1' filename
```

should do it. Below is a sample output

```
"KSDP01","01962424813"
"KSDP01","01962424813"
"KSDP01","8801962424813"
KSDP01,01962424813
KSDP01,1962424813
KSDP01,8801962424813
KSDP01,01962424813
KSDP01,1962424813
KSDP01,8801962424813
"KSDP01","1962424813"
"KSDP01","1962424813"
"KSDP01","8801962424813"
ASDP11,01959969994
"ASDP01","8801962424183"
"KSDP11","801962424183"
"CSDP10","01962424183"
"ASDP09","1962424183"
CSDP13,8801962424183
KSDP08,801962424183
ASDP07,01962424183
CSDP05,1962424183
"ASDP01","8801962424183",
"KSDP11","801962424183",
"CSDP10","01962424183"
"ASDP09","1962424183"
CSDP13,8801962424183
KSDP08,801962424183
ASDP07,01962424183
CSDP05,1962424183
CSDP06,01912401927
```

Comment: awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," '($1 ~ /19/){temp=$1;$1=$2;$2=temp}1' xyz.txt 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
getting error like this "(

Comment: @KaziNymulHaqueKanon : Are you on a solaris?

Comment: Yes.I am on SunOS.

Comment: What is the file source? Do a `dos2unix xyz.txt` before the `awk` command and see what the result is

Comment: don't use Sun's default awk.  Check for an alternative version most likely installed as well.

Comment: @KaziNymulHaqueKanon : karafka's comment is inline with what I see [\[ here \]](http://www.unix.com/302625357-post1.html?s=2354c0a2f631099a45ec41abda3b0b1c)

Comment: still happening :(

Comment: @sjsam After using nawk instead of awk, works just fine. Many thanks. :)